# Fork travel for 16" frame size, 26" wheel hardtail

Tags: fork, 26-inch, hardtail

I would like to ask question if my frame and setup are OK for me.

I am 5'6.5" (169 cm) tall and I am using a Merida HFS 1000, frame size 16".  Please tell me what fork travel should I set up with this. Right now I am using an SR Suntour Epicon 100 mm travel.  Should I decrease the travel to 80 mm?

Answer (score 2):

Acceptable fork travel is primarily defined by particular bicycle frame design, not by rider's height or other parameters. More specifically, it is important to maintain the same or close distance between the front wheel's axle and the fork's crown, as stipulated by the manufacturer, when changing forks or changing travel.

If your fork is the original one that came with the bicycle from the factory, then recommended travel for the bicycle is 100 mm. Otherwise, if it was replaced by you or a previous owner, you can try to figure out what was the travel on the original fork.

There are several models that I can find by the name "Merida HFS 1000", and the fork travel range for them varies from 80 to 120 mm. You'll have to be more specific with the model name and frame year to figure it out.

Lastly, if you feel that your current bike handles fine, there is no point in experimenting with a shorter fork, unless you can easily swap back and forth between them to find the best one that suites you.

Comment: Thank you Grigory. I appreciate so much.  Right now I am using a 120mm travel fork which I intend to mode it to 80 to 100mm.  I feel OK with the ride anyway, but I feel faster when I used to have the adjustable fork at shorter travel.  Thanks again.